# Radio Button Not working in Yii2

Tags: css, yii2, radio-button

When i create radio buttons with simple html it is working fine:

```
<div class="example-wrap">

            <div class="radio-custom radio-primary">
                <input type="radio" id="inputRadiosUnchecked" name="inputRadios" />
                <label for="inputRadiosUnchecked">Unchecked</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio-custom radio-primary">
                <input type="radio" id="inputRadiosChecked" name="inputRadios" checked />
                <label for="inputRadiosChecked">Checked</label>
            </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

but when i integrate the same in yii2 it is not working.it shows the radio button but its not clickable.i am new to yii2 please tell what i am doing wrong:
my yii2 integrated code for radio button is this:

```
                <div class="radio-custom radio-primary">
                   <?= $form->field($model, 'settings[esign_ssn_authentication]')->radio(['label' => 'Option 1', 'value' => 1, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>
                   <label for="inputRadiosUnchecked">Unchecked</label>  
</div>
</div>
```

but in yii2 its showing like this :
[image]

Dont know why its showing radio button with the label also.

Comment: What do you mean by "not clickable"? Does it generate one or two radio buttons? And if one is it already selected?

Comment: with my code in yii2 listed above it creates two radio buttons and when i click the radio button it does not get selected.like normaly radio buttons do

Comment: I'm not sure now but isn't the `radio()` method generating only one radio button? I don't know what is generating the "unchecked" radio in your case. For more than one use `radioList()` method.

Comment: ok leave the "Unchecked" radio just tell me why it is not selecting the radio button when i click it?

Comment: No idea. Have you got some plugin that modifies the look of them? Maybe that is the reason. Your images indicate that these radio buttons are not the standard ones.

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap material theme. they are from that theme.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check like this

```
<?php 
$model->type='1'; //for default selected
$type=array(1,2,3,4);
echo $form->field($model, 'type')->radioList($type, ['itemOptions' => ['class' =>'radio-inline']]) ?>
```